# Double integral of floor function and exponential function over rectangular region

Tags: calculus

I am not getting any idea how to deal with this two sums of double integral where functions and rectangular domain is given as

1. $\lfloor x+y\rfloor$ and $1\leq x\leq 3$, $2\leq y\leq 5$
2. $e^{\max(x^2,y^2)}$ and $0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 1$.

For first one I use inequality $x+y-1<\lfloor x+y\rfloor\leq x+y$, and I just get hint that my answer will in between $27$ and $33$. But how I will get exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards the first integral, we have that
$$\iint_R\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy=\sum_{k=1+2}^{3+5}k\cdot\mbox{Area}(R\cap\{(x,y): k\leq x+y<k+1\}).$$
Make a drawing of the rectangle $R=[1,3]\times [2,5]$  with the lines $x+y=k$ for $k=3,\dots,8$ and you will easily evaluate the areas of the intersections given in the above formula. Finally you should obtain
$$\iint_R\lfloor x+y\rfloor dxdy=3\cdot\frac{1}{2}+4\cdot\frac{3}{2}+5\cdot\frac{4}{2}+6\cdot\frac{3}{2}+7\cdot\frac{1}{2}+8\cdot 0=30.$$

As regards the second one note that
\begin{align*}\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}e^{\max(x^2,y^2)}dxdy
&=
\int_{x=0}^1\left(\int_{y=0}^xe^{x^2}dy\right)dx+
\int_{y=0}^1\left(\int_{x=0}^ye^{y^2}dx\right)dy\\
&=\int_{x=0}^1xe^{x^2}dx+\int_{y=0}^1ye^{y^2}dy\\
&=2\int_{x=0}^1xe^{x^2}dx=[e^{x^2}]_0^1=e-1.
\end{align*}

Comment: is there k+1 instead of k in the end of formula.?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What about the second integral? Have you the final result?

Comment: and in the second formula of second sum i am not getting what to fill in place of "?"..

Comment: @omkarGirkar See my edited answer.

Comment: yes..i was also thinking about the same values in place of "?" so that integral would be solvable(cheating!) but didn't get why?i think you break the domain into two pieces by line y=x and then put limits..am i right? but still not get the logic behind this..but thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

For a given value of $x$ and integer $k$, $$\lfloor x+y\rfloor = \left\{ \begin{matrix} \lfloor x \rfloor + k  & \text{for $k \le y   < k + 1 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor $,} \\ \lfloor x \rfloor + k+1  & \text{for $k + 1 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor \le y   < k + 1$.}\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
Consequently, for an integer $k$,
$$\int_{k}^{k+1} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \,dy = \int_{k}^{k + 1 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor} (\lfloor x \rfloor+ k) \,dy + \int_{k + 1 - x + \lfloor x \rfloor}^{k+1} (\lfloor x \rfloor +k +1 )\,dy = k +x.$$

Therefore,
$$\int_{1}^{3}\int_{2}^{5} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \, dy \, dx = \int_{1}^{3}\left(\int_{2}^{3} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \, dy+\int_{3}^{4} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \, dy+\int_{4}^{5} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \, dy\right)\,dx$$ implies
$$\int_{1}^{3}\int_{2}^{5} \lfloor x+y\rfloor \, dy \, dx = \int_{1}^{3} [(2+x)+(3+x)+(4+x) ]\,dx = \color{red}{30}.$$